# How to get values of different columns, but from the same line?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I am trying to get values from different columns, but from the same line. For example: get username, password, email address and by only knowing the username. So for example: user logins and wants to see some data related to them that is stored in the database, so I would get all the data from the line and then only display the data that I need, like his email address.

Example:

```
id  | Username | Password |   Email    | 
----+----------+----------+------------+
 1  | Ane      | 1234567  |  ok@ok.com |
 2  | Angi     | 1234567  |  ok@ok.com |
 3  | Bobby    | 1234567  |  ok@ok.com |
 4  | Denis    | 1234567  |  ok@ok.com |
 5  | Jerry    | 1234567  |  ok@ok.com |
 6  | Mikha    | 1234567  |  ok@ok.com |
```

So I want to get for example all the values from Username Mikha, so:

ID, Username, Password, Email

6, Ane, 1234567, ok@ok.com

Comment: There are ***100000*** of simple SQL tutorials on the web. ***Read a few***

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? A `fetch` on a result set should work.

Comment: @chris85 I think they are asking for the query first, the how do I make it work in PHP will probably come next

Comment: A little quick search and you pretty much get the answer for something as basic as this... take a look at PHP's [mysqli prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) - First example, specifically

Comment: FYI: **Never store plain text passwords!** PHP provides [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them. If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you [**don't escape passwords**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/5914775) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply type:

```
select (id,Username,Password,Email) from theTable where username = "Mikha";
```

This will printout all the value from row where username = "Mikha" exist.

Comment: Simply type that ***where*** In the cloud maybe? On your iPad?

Comment: @CodeNinja ummm.... no.....

Comment: @code Ninja   it is not from Database;  , is it from table with where condition.

Comment: what i can see, he is asking how to printout all the value from the database, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: About that you are quite correct. But an answer that says ___simply type....___ is not very  helpful. **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: And now in your hurry you are making matters worse

Comment: The parentheses are unnecessary.